# Laravel asset vs relative paths

Tags: laravel, url

In laravel you can do one of these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
<img src="/storage/img/logo.svg">
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>

<!-- same as the following -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
<img src="{{asset('storage/img/logo.svg')}}">
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

The first is a relative path (relative to the public dir) and the second generates an absolute path.

Besides that, is there any difference in the results? At least in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox I could not perceive any difference.

Is there any advantage of using one over another? Maybe in performance or compability? Does one loads faster than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *potentially* major differences.

The `asset` helper is CDN-aware. Setting the `app.asset_url` config value causes `asset()` to append that URL to every link it generates, which is very useful if you're using a CDN.

In addition, it'll save you a lot of work if your app winds up hosted in a subdirectory - all you have to do is set `app.url`, and `asset` will spit out the right URLs to `js/app.js` (i.e. `/a/sub/folder/js/app.js`).

Comment: Thanks! Could you also give an example of how to set app.url to point to subdirectories when using asset? That would be fantastic!

Comment: @StudentofSciences You'd set `app.url` to something like `https://example.com/foo/`.

Comment: Where I can set up the 'app.url'? I mean, in which file I can set up 'app.url'? Please, tell me where the file is located. I'm newbie to Laravel, so I'm sorry if it is a basic question.

Comment: @StudentofSciences `config/app.php`. Look for `url`.

Comment: Considering that the `config/app.php` reads an env variable it would be better to set your url in the `.env` file with ASSET_URL=https//...

Comment: @AndreaMauro To clarify, look in `config/app.php` to figure out what it's set to, and where that comes from. I agree that doing it via the `.env` is best, but it's possible in an existing app that someone's made it pull from elsewhere, or hard coded.